# What is a pseudo-virtual function in C++?

Tags: c++

What is a pseudo-virtual function in C++?

Comment: The context is a mechanism to optimize multithreaded animation and mesh morpher systems on a 3d engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it's not a term that appears anywhere with an official definition.

Perhaps someone is talking about [simulated dynamic binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Edit: a swift web search suggests that someone might have implemented their own dynamic polymorphism, so they perhaps have their own vtables. "Pseudo-virtual" functions would then be functions accessed through their mechanism, rather than actually being virtual functions as their C++ compiler understands them.

One reason to do this would be to implement [multi-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).

Do you have any context you can point us at?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be something related to simulated dynamic binding. The context is a mechanism to optimize multithreaded animation and mesh morpher systems on a 3d engine, so it makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard this term.  I'd guess they're either talking about the [Non-Virtual Interface idiom (NVI)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) or they're talking about building a dispatch table of function pointers which is how one might implement polymorphism/virtual functions in C (and in fact is how C++ compilers do it behind the scenes).

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the term to used to refer to multimethods (in C++ these are usually implemented using an array of function pointers where the selector offset determined by the code at runtime):

```
(*multiMethod[ index ])()
```

The multiMethod array is just an array of function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A virtual function with a declaration.

```
class Foo
{
    int* bar;

    Foo() : bar(0) { bar = new int; }
    virtual ~Foo() { delete bar; }
}
```

This has a pseudo-virtual destructor, since it does something in the declaration. Here is a pure virtual declaration:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() { }
    virtual ~Foo()=0;
}
```

At least, this is how I learned it.

Comment: You probably mean a **definition**. Anything that can be used has a declaration. Also, pure virtual functions can also be defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, I always forget that the terms used in describing a programming language must be entirely unambiguous. Sorry, I have no formal training (yet?).

Comment: If that's how you learned it, then whoever taught you did not understand what "pseudo" means.